# How to convert an object into List (of Object)

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a a List (of Object) from object which is from the third party. The below code can work.
Is it better way to do it?

```
Dim lstStudents as New List(of Student)
Dim classRoom as integer=101
Dim thisStudents As New Students(classRoom)
For Each objStudent As Student In thisStudents
        lstStudents.Add(objStudent)
Next
```

Comment: Also check sortedlist with key value pair. where you can use key as StudentId  and value can be your student object so It can be easy search student object only by studentId

Answer (score -1):

You could use LINQ to simplify the code a bit, e.g.

```vb
lstStudents = thisStudents.ToList()
```

For that to work as is, the `Students` class would have to implement the `IEnumerable(Of Student)` interface. If it only implements `IEnumerable`, you'd have to do this:

```vb
lstStudents = thisStudents.Cast(Of Student)().ToList()
```

Comment: Students class only implements IEnumerable. I get error that 'Cast' is not a member of Students

Comment: It's an extension method, so you have to have referenced the appropriate assembly and imported the appropriate namespace. That's generally done by default but you can do it manually. Read the documentation for the Enumerable.Cast(Of T) meeting to find out which ones they are.